# New hardware same hard drive with same OS

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive

I have recently purchased a new motherboard and CPU and I was wondering if there is a way to get Windows from my old hard-drive to load without performing a fresh install. Ubuntu seems to load perfectly fine from the same HD but windows just crashes and reboots upon starting up.

Is there something special I need to do to Windows to get it to load? I ask because I can't be bothered re downloading all my applications again because there is over 100GB of applications that I use quite often (Games, Apps etc..).

I understand that Linux and Windows are completely different but it seems stupid that Windows won't load where as Ubuntu will load perfectly fine from the same Hard Drive.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To begin with, are you able to boot Windows into safe mode? (Press F8 before Windows boots to bring up the boot menu, and select safe mode.)

Comment: No I cannot boot into safe mode either. I didn't notice this before but there is a quick blue screen of death that appears and then it reboots. I'm guessing I will have to do a reinstall?

Comment: In theory you should be able to reuse the disk if you are able to uninstall the chipset drivers so that old motherboard's settings are not loaded at boot. Try putting the disk back in the old computer, go to devioce manager and select uninstall for everything under display adapters, processors and system devices. The shut down the computer and move the disk into the new computer and try booting. This *might* be a waste of time, though.

Answer (score 0):

After the initial install I believe Windows removes it's generic drivers to stop software bloat, your best bet is to either re-install windows OR do a system restore to the time when your system still had those generic drivers, system restore should not remove your files but  it may remove installed programs.

I suggest a backup before attempting system restore just in case.